# Does or does not pthread_join() allow execution on calling thread to continue?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

**edit:**
I made the wrong assumption that threads started running on `pthread_join` when they actually start running on `pthread_create`.

---

I'm learning to use Posix threads, and I've read that:
`pthread_join() - wait for thread termination`

So, in the code sample, main's exit(0) is not reached until both started threads end.
But after the first call to pthread_join(), main continues executing, because the second call to pthread_join() actually runs, and the message in between is printed.
So how's this? does main continue executing while both threads aren't finished yet? or doesn't it?
I know this isn't a reliable way of testing, but the second test message always gets printed after both threads are finished, no matter how long the loop is. (at least on my machine when I tried it)

`void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{
    char *message = (char *) ptr;
    for( int a = 0; a < 1000; ++a )
        printf( "%s - %i\n", message, a );
    return NULL;
}
//
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    char message1[] = "Thread 1";
    char message2[] = "Thread 2";
    int  iret1, iret2;
    //
    iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);
    iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);
    //
    pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
    printf( "Let's see when is this printed...\n" );
    pthread_join( thread2, NULL); 
    printf( "And this one?...\n" );
    //
    printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",iret1);
    printf("Thread 2 returns: %d\n",iret2);
    exit(0);
}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `pthread_join` waits for the thread to finish or returns immediately if the thread is already done.

So in your case

```
pthread_join( thread1, NULL); /* Start waiting for thread1. */
printf( "Let's see when is this printed...\n" ); /* Done waiting for thread1. */

pthread_join( thread2, NULL); /* Start waiting for thread2. */
printf( "And this one?...\n" ); /* Done waiting for thread2. */
```

> But after the first call to pthread_join(), main continues executing,
>   because the second call to pthread_join() actually runs, and the
>   message in between is printed.

False. `pthread_join` waits unless thread1 is already done.

Comment: Oh right, because the thread already started on pthread_create. thx

Answer (score 3):

```
pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
```

The main thread waits here on this join call till `thread1` completes its job. Once `thread1` completes execution main thread will proceed ahead and execute the next statement `printf`.

```
printf( "Let's see when is this printed...\n" );
```

Again, Main thread will wait here till `thread2` completes its job.

```
pthread_join( thread2, NULL);
```

Once `thread2` completes its job the main thread moves ahead and the next statement which is the `printf` is executed.

```
printf( "And this one?...\n" );
```

The sequence will work in the above mentioned way.Probably, this happens all too soon that the traces you see makes it confusing.
Also, Do not using `printf` to see behavior of multithreaded programs can be quite misleading, the order of the printf may not always indicate the correct control flow Since it is timing based and flushing of the buffers to stdout may not happen in sasme order as the prints were executed accross threads.

Answer (score 3):

`pthread_join()` does not return (blocking the calling thread) until the thread being joined has terminated. If the thread has already terminated, then it returns straight away.

In your test, both threads do exit, and so of course you'll see all the messages printed from the main thread. When the first message is printed, you know that `thread1` is complete; when the second is printed you know that `thread2` is also complete. This will probably happen quite quickly after the first, since both threads were doing the same amount of work at roughly the same time.

Answer (score 2):

If the first pthread_join returns immediately, that would suggest that the first thread has already finished executing. What does the output look like? Do you see any "Thread 1 - n" output after "Let's see when this is printed"?